# Xamarin.Forms 2.4 - OnIdiom bug

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using the OnIdiom tag in my XAML on several pages and sometimes several times on one page, and it worked fine when I used it with Xamarin.Forms versions prior to 2.4. However, when I updated to 2.4 and tried to deploy my application (without changing any code), I got errors from several places where I used OnIdiom, all of them are "No property, bindable property, or event found for '{The property I tried to use OnIdiom for goes here}', or mistmatching type between value and property.".
For instance, the following XAML code:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource, Converter={StaticResource BinaryToImageConverter}}" Aspect="AspectFit">
      <Image.HeightRequest>
             <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Phone="150" Tablet="300" />
      </Image.HeightRequest>
</Image>
```

Results in the following error:
"No property, bindable property, or event found for 'HeightRequest', or mismatching type between value and property.".

I've noticed several things I would like to mention: 
 1. I used the [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)] attribute in the code-behind for all my XAML pages, I noticed that when I remove it from the pages that cause the errors, I no longer get the errors and those pages also load fine. I do not want to remove these attributes since I believe they speed things up considering the XAML compilations happens during compile-time and not runtime.
 2. This may be a coincidence, but I noticed all the errors I am getting are from places where I used OnIdiom for either the HeightRequest or the WidthRequest property and where I used x:TypeArguments="x:Double". I used the OnIdiom tag on more properties and other pages which do not result in an error for some reason.
 3. I found a bug report that seems to fit my description on Xamarin's bugzilla (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=58922) and I saw a comment there where the person said defining an x:Key attribute for the OnIdiom tag solved the problem for him. I tried that, but it didn't work for me.

EDIT (20/11/17): For those who experience a similar issue, I have found a workaround that can work for now: Define the OnIdiom instances as resources with keys (you can do that on an application level, page level or control level) and let controls consume them using the keys.